# Xamarin - Entry completed event triggered before scan end

Tags: c#, xamarin, barcode-scanner

I'm using a LS2208 scanner in my application and while i'm scanning a bar code, the completed event of my entry is triggered "before the scan end".
There is my entry's code :

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <Entry x:Name="txtNumColis" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                                    Text="{Binding TxtNumColis,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                                    Keyboard="{Binding SearchKeyboard}" 
                                                    FontSize="{Binding FontSizeSmall}"
                                                    Style="{StaticResource Key=MainEntryStyle}" Placeholder="Numéro"
                                                    ReturnCommand="{Binding SearchSODCommand}" 
                                                    ReturnCommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference txtNumColis}, Path=Text}">

                                    <Entry.Behaviors>
                                        <!--<b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="TextChanged" Command="{Binding SearchEntryTextChangeCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference txtNumColis},Path=Text}"/>-->
                                        <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Completed" Command="{Binding SearchEntryTextChangeCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference txtNumColis},Path=Text}"/>
                                    </Entry.Behaviors>
                                </Entry>
                            </StackLayout>
```

And when I scan a bar'code which should return "001011", there is what I have in my `SearchEntryTextChangeCommand`
[image]

Thank's for your help.

Comment: why are you using both `ReturnCommand` and `Completed`?  Is your scanner configured to append a CRLF after the scan completes?

Comment: The ReturnCommand was a test. In fact, im using only completed event. And yes, when i'm using scan in a notepad, I have a CR

Comment: For your device, I found that you can trigger enter at the end of the scan by scanning the barcode setting. Have you set it? If it is set, try to print it out to see if the data is correct.